# Using current database name in T-SQL has Using statement

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-agent

I have application runs T-SQL statements to update more than one database 
the problem is i'm using the following t-sql

```
USE [msdb]
GO
DECLARE @jobId BINARY(16)
EXEC  msdb.dbo.sp_add_job @job_name=N'test2', 
        @enabled=1, 
        @start_step_id=1, 
        @notify_level_eventlog=0, 
        @notify_level_email=2, 
        @notify_level_netsend=2, 
        @notify_level_page=2, 
        @delete_level=0, 
        @description=N'', 
        @category_name=N'[Uncategorized (Local)]', 
        @owner_login_name=N'sa', 
        @notify_email_operator_name=N'', 
        @notify_netsend_operator_name=N'', 
        @notify_page_operator_name=N'', @job_id = @jobId OUTPUT
select @jobId
GO
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_add_jobserver @job_name=N'test2', @server_name = N'AMR-PC\SQL2008'
GO
USE [msdb]
GO
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_add_jobstep @job_name=N'test2', @step_name=N'test', 
        @step_id=1, 
        @cmdexec_success_code=0, 
        @on_success_action=1, 
        @on_fail_action=2, 
        @retry_attempts=0, 
        @retry_interval=0, 
        @os_run_priority=0, @subsystem=N'TSQL', 
        @command=N'EXEC sp_MSforeachdb ''
    EXEC sp_MSforeachtable @command1=''''DBCC DBREINDEX (''''''''*'''''''')'''', 
        @replacechar=''''*''''''', 
        @database_name=N'Client5281', 
        @output_file_name=N'C:\Documents and Settings\Amr\Desktop\Scheduel Reports\report', 
        @flags=2
GO

USE [msdb]
GO
DECLARE @schedule_id int
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_add_jobschedule @job_name=N'test2', @name=N'test', 
        @enabled=1, 
        @freq_type=8, 
        @freq_interval=1, 
        @freq_subday_type=1, 
        @freq_subday_interval=0, 
        @freq_relative_interval=0, 
        @freq_recurrence_factor=1, 
        @active_start_date=20100517, 
        @active_end_date=99991231, 
        @active_start_time=0, 
        @active_end_time=235959, @schedule_id = @schedule_id OUTPUT
select @schedule_id
GO
```

and i'm using (USE [msdb]) before any block and i want to get database name to replace this `@database_name=N'**Client5281**',` with the current database name instead of  ([msdb]) that i'm using.

i hope that i explained what i want well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

beacause i execute this query from vb.net application i used replace() method to replace the dbname by current dbname. thanks for all tried to help me.

Answer (score 2):

Remove all `use [msdb]`, they are not needed. Since the script fully qualifies the procedure name with the db name and schema name, there is no need to USE before invoking the procedure. You can then simply use `@database_name=DB_NAME ()`.

Another solution is to use SQLCMD variables, which SSMS recognizes when [properly configured](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174187.aspx):

```
:setvar dbname Client5281
...
USE [msdb]
GO
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_add_jobstep @job_name=N'test2', @step_name=N'test', 
        ...
        @database_name=N'$(dbname)', 
        ...
GO
```

Comment: I feel that ur answer is nearly correct but this case doesn't work with me. thanks

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do that is dynamic SQL.  For example:

```
declare @sql nvarchar(max)
set @sql = N'use ' + @database_name + '
    go
    declare @schedule_id int
    ...'
exec (@sql)
```

In response to your comment, you can save the current database name like:

```
declare @db varchar(256)
set @db = DB_NAME()
```

And then change:

```
@database_name=N'Client5281',
```

to:

```
@db,
```

You will also have to remove any `go` statements, as those limit the variable scope.

Comment: thanks for ur help but i don't want to replace ([msdb]) by current database name but i want to replace this Client5281 in database_name=N'**Client5281**' by current database name because if i used db_name() when i use [msdb] it will return [msdb] but i want to return current database that i'm running this script for it